# Windows prompt: ISO 8601 date?

Tags: windows, prompt, cmd

How do I set the command line prompt in Windows to display
current [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date and time (e.g. 2009-09-08T13:01:56)
instead of the default of current directory?

**Update**. Set it by:
right click My Computer/Properties/tab Advanced/Environment Variables/System Variables/New/
Variable name=PROMPT and Variable value=$DT$T $P$G /OK/OK/OK.
Regional settings must be set such that "Time format" is
"HH:mm:ss" and "Short date format" is "yyyy-MM-dd".

Comment: Use "prompt /?" to read about the options.  /? works for pretty much all the old standard dos commands.

Answer (score 3):

This will give you the current date and time formatted according to the system regional settings:

```
prompt $D $T$G
```

I don't think there is a way to specify the datetime format.

Comment: You can do this by creating a global environment variable called PROMPT, with the value '$D $T$G'

Comment: Windows 10 now has a "Data Formats" menu where you can change the "Short Date" to YYYY-MM-DD which _is properly reflected_ in `prompt $d`!